# How to force using external storage for saving downloaded files in android?

Tags: android, android-download-manager, android-external-storage, android-internal-storage

I am trying to save my files using DownloadManager.Request. I use request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() but the file is still saved on internal storage. How can I force it to be directly saved on external storage? My external storage is completely available and the permission is granted in Manifest.

Here is my code for download.

```html
request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
            request.setTitle(track.getTitle());
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("trackType", track.get_id());
            request.addRequestHeader("Authorization", Utils.getToken(currentActivity));
            request.addRequestHeader("Client", "androidMobileApp");
            request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_HIDDEN);

            startDownloadNotification(track);

            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: trackType is a directory? And what is the other parameter? Value please.

Comment: `but the file is still saved on internal storage. `. Where exactly? Please provide full path.

Comment: @greenapps yes trackType is a directory. The other parameter is a String and is supposed to be the name of the downloaded file.

Here is the full path:
/storage/emulated/0/trackType/

Comment: You have not mentioned if that directory exists. Nor is there code that first checks if the directory exists. You should do that before you ask someone to put a file in it.

Comment: @greenapps I do make the directory using: private File direct = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/trackType"); and I do check if it exists before download using if (!direct.exists()) {
            direct.mkdirs();
        }

Comment: You should check the return value of mkdirs() as it might fail to create a directory in which case it returns false. You should return then. And not continue with the code. if (!direct.exists()) if (!direct.mkdirs()){toast... return;}

Comment: @greenapps Thank you but what should I do when it returns false? I really want to be able to save files on SD card.

Comment: So are you saying that the directory does not exist at all? That you really cannot create it? You dont have to talk about downloading then. Your post should have been about 'how to create a directory'. Android version? SD card? /storage/emulated/0/trackType/  is NOT on a removable SD card.

Comment: `and the permission is granted in Manifest.`. Which permission? No. It is only requested. Maybe the user does not grant it. This is possible on Android 6 and above.